# RegExp match word till space or character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match all the words starting with # and words between 2 # (see example)

```
var str = "#The test# rain in #SPAIN stays mainly in the #plain"; 
var res = str.match(/(#)[^\s]+/gi);
```

The result will be `["#The", "#SPAIN", "#plain"]` but it should be `["#The test#", "#SPAIN", "#plain"]`

Extra: would be nice if the result would be without the #.

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Well, try [`#\w+(?:(?: +\w+)*#)?`](https://regex101.com/r/mY5zL9/1). I doubt it is that easy to get rid of the trailing `#` with a regex.

Comment: @E.Fortes Answer by Wiktor not me, he has added answer with explanation, upvote and accept if that has solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
/#\w+(?:(?: +\w+)*#)?/g
```

See the [demo  here](https://regex101.com/r/mY5zL9/1)

The regex matches:

- `#` -  a hash symbol
- `\w+` - one or more alphanumeric and underscore characters
- `(?:(?: +\w+)*#)?` - one or zero occurrence of:

  - `(?: +\w+)*` - zero  or more occurrences of one or more spaces followed with one or more word characters followed with
  - `#` - a hash symbol

**NOTE**: If there can be characters other than word characters (those in the `[A-Za-z0-9_]` range), you can replace `\w` with `[^ #]`:

```
/#[^ #]+(?:(?: +[^ #]+)*#)?/g
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/bL9vX2/4)

```js
var re = /#[^ #]+(?:(?: +[^ #]+)*#)?/g;
var str = '#The test-mode# rain in #SPAIN stays mainly in the #plain #SPAIN has #the test# and more #here';
var m = str.match(re);
if (m) {

  // Using ES6 Arrow functions
  m = m.map(s => s.replace(/#$/g, ''));

  // ES5 Equivalent
  /*m = m.map(function(s) {
    return s.replace(/#$/g, '');
  });*/ // getting rid of the trailing #
  document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(m, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: I updated the snippet to also remove the trailing `#`.

Comment: I added another regex in case there are other than word characters between the hash symbols. The main point is that there should be a space inside. Snippet is also updated.

Comment: Thank you for your great help and the good explanation. Did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this regex.

```
#(?:\b[\s\S]*?\b#|\w+)
```

- `(?:` opens a [non capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) for alternation
- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `\w` matches a [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- `[\s\S]` matches any character

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yQ5rP2/1) (use with `g` global [flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html))

Comment: Thank you bobble. I already used this one: /#[^ #]+(?:(?: +[^ #]+)*#)?/g